# How to sumarize correctly as “Leave Time” + "Total Time" - mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum

OK - i've changed that concept. In mysql database i've created "leave" table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+
|ID_LEAVE|ID_WORKER| FNAME   | LNAME   | BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE              | 
+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+-----------
| 1      |   1     | DAVID   | BUCS    |2019-03-19 07:00:00  |2019-03-19 15:00:00    | 
+--------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------------+----------- 
| 2      |   2     | MARK    | GREEN   |2019-03-21 07:00:00  |2019-03-21 15:00:00    |
+--------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
```

"Workers" table:

```
+----------+---------+---------+
|ID_WORKER |  FNAME  | LNAME   |
+----------+---------+----------
| 1        |  DAVID  |  BUCS   |
+----------+---------+----------
| 2        |  MARK   |  GREEN  |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

"Orders" table:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+
|ID_ORDER  |  DESC_ORDER  | NUMBER_ORDER  |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
| 20       |  TEST        |  TEST         |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

"Order_status" table:

```
+----------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
| Id_status|ID_WORKER| ID_ORDER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE          | ORDER_DONE |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| 30       |   1     |    20   |2019-03-18 06:50:35  |2019-03-18 15:21:32|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 31       |   1     |    20   |2019-03-20 06:44:12  |2019-03-20 15:11:23|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 32       |   1     |    20   |2019-03-22 06:50:20  |2019-03-22 12:22:33|  YES       |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 33       |   2     |    20   |2019-03-18 06:45:11  |2019-03-18 15:14:45|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 34       |   2     |    20   |2019-03-20 06:50:22  |2019-03-20 15:10:32|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 35       |   2     |    20   |2019-03-22 06:54:11  |2019-03-22 11:23:45|  YES       |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+
```

What i've done:

I can to sumarize "total time" of each other workers (in order_status table) on the order including with sumarizing "leave time" from Leave table. I have selected workers (LNAME, FNAME) orders (DESC_ORDER and NUMBER_ORDER) and "TOTAL TIME" on order from each other workers correctly too. I wrote the mysql command in below:

```
SELECT workers.fname, 
       workers.lname, 
       order_statusAgg.number_order,
       workers.id_worker,
       order_statusAgg.desc_order, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)) AS 'TOTAL TIME', 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(leaveAgg.ltime)) AS 'LEAVE TIME' 
FROM   workers 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT leave.id_worker, SUM((Time_to_sec(leave.end_date) - 
                       Time_to_sec(leave.begin_date))) AS ltime
FROM leave
GROUP BY leave.id_worker
) leaveAgg
               ON leaveAgg.id_worker = workers.id_worker
       INNER JOIN (
SELECT order_status.id_worker, orders.number_order, orders.desc_order, SUM((Time_to_sec(order_status.end_date) - 
                       Time_to_sec(order_status.begin_date))) AS stime
FROM order_status
           INNER JOIN orders 
               ON orders.id_order = order_status.id_order
GROUP BY order_status.id_worker
) order_statusAgg
               ON workers.id_worker = order_statusAgg.id_worker 

WHERE  order_statusAgg.number_order LIKE 'TEST'
GROUP BY workers.id_worker
```

Then after that command i get:

```
    +---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    |  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER | DESC_ORDER | TOTAL TIME | LEAVE_TIME   | 
    +---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    |  DAVID  |  BUCS   | TEST          | TEST       | 22:30:21   |   8:00:00    |   
    +---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    |  MARK   |  GREEN  | TEST          | TEST       | 21:19:18   |   8:00:00    |   
    +---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

what i'd like to do next:

What i'd like to do next: I'm trying sumarize all of them, i mean: TOTAL TIME + LEAVE_TIME for each Worker. For example:

```
 +---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER | DESC_ORDER | TOTAL TIME | LEAVE_TIME   | SUM_TIME |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+----------+
|  DAVID  |  BUCS   | TEST          | TEST       | 22:30:21   |   8:00:00    | 30:30:21 |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+----------+
|  MARK   |  GREEN  | TEST          | TEST       | 21:19:18   |   8:00:00    | 29:19:18 | 
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+----------+
```

i've tried add to at the top query:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.ttime) + SUM(leaveAgg.stime)) AS 'SUM_TIME';
```

But i know that's a bad idea. So i have no clue how to solve it. Has someone idea how to solve it? Any ideas. Thx very much for any help!

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  That code will not run in any dbms system, except maybe on old MySQL.

Comment: Looks like a step in the right direction to me. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Eric But i wrote today that code without my trying new code and that worked

Comment: @Prochu1991 It may work.  It doesn't mean you should do it.  There's a reason why it's not allowed by other dbms, including newer version of MySQL.

Comment: @Prochu1991 Let's take your inner most query `SELECT order_status.id_worker
 , orders.number_order
 , orders.desc_order
 , SUM((Time_to_sec(order_status.end_date) - Time_to_sec(order_status.begin_date))) AS stime
FROM order_status
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id_order = order_status.id_order
GROUP BY order_status.id_worker`.  If this worker has multiple orders, which orders will be included when you are grouping by worker?  MySQL would just randomly pick an order.